# FlagsAttribute what for?

Tags: .net, vb.net, attributes

What is the difference between the code bellow

```
' no Flags'
Public Enum MyEnum
  Monday = 1
  Tuesday = 2
  Wednesday = 4
  Thursday = 8
End Enum
```

and

```
<Flags()> _ 
Public Enum MyEnum
  Monday = 1
  Tuesday = 2
  Wednesday = 4
  Thursday = 8
End Enum
```

I do the

```
Dim days As MyEnum = MyEnum.Monday Or MyEnum.Tuesday Or MyEnum.Wednesday 

If (days And MyEnum.Tuesday) = MyEnum.Tuesday Then
  Console.WriteLine("Tuesday OK") ' here'
Else
  Console.WriteLine("Tuesday NOK")
End If

If (days And MyEnum.Thursday ) = MyEnum.Thursday Then
  Console.WriteLine("Thursday OK")
Else
  Console.WriteLine("Thursday NOK") ' here'
End If
```

and obtain the same result in both cases(with or without FlagAttribute).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, it tells the CLR that the values of the enum can be combined. Without this attribute, combining the values would result in an unknown value (but it would still be valid). With the attribute, the combination is correctly interpreted

Without the `Flags` attributes :

```
' Gives "Monday, Tuesday" '
Dim s As String = (MyEnum.Monday Or MyEnum.Tuesday).ToString()
```

Without the `Flags` attributes :

```
' Gives "3" '
Dim s As String = (MyEnum.Monday Or MyEnum.Tuesday).ToString()
```

Comment: OK, but **practically** (without `ToString()` output difference) does it have any significance?

Comment: It can also affect XML serialization. Serialization of a combination of values will fail if the enum doesn't have the Flags attribute...

Comment: can you provide a link for the Serialization issue?

Comment: I don't have a link, but you can test it very easily... Just try to serialize an unknown combination of unknown values, you will get an exception if the Flags attribute isn't there.

Comment: I have posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283088/flags-attribute-seems-to-have-no-effect quoting your answer.  Please would you take a look? +1.

Answer (score 2):

It *only* affects  ToString()

Comment: so, apparently, is not so useful?!

Comment: It is useful in some situations, but never critical.

Comment: @SerHio, No, it doesn't fail. Just tested it.

Comment: have you tested with combination of values, or just simple values?

Comment: Several variations and with Soap and Binary. Not sure about the other XML serialization yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Also it impacts ToString() output.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx)

Comment: why do you say `Also`, do you know other "impacts"?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer with VB code but flags are very useful in certain circumstances. The example you have demonstrated isn't so good. Imagine you've got something more like:

```
enum Format
{
  Bold = 1,
  Italic = 2,
  Underlined = 4
}
```

Then you could specify the `Format` to be:

```
Format format = Format.Bold | Format.Italic;
// Then a check to see if the format is bold or italic should both pass.
```

Now it is both **bold** and *italic* (equal to 3). You wouldn't be able to set this without the flags attribute though. It kind of prevents options being mutally exclusive. To do the above without flags you'd have to do:

```
enum Format
{
  Bold,
  BoldUnderlined,
  BoldItalic,
  BoldUnderlinedItalic,  
  Underlined,  
  Italic,
  ItalicUnderlined
}
```

No way near as nice.

Comment: Not according to MSDN you can't http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx. Although I've not yet tried it.

Comment: You **can**, as you can see in my example. Try yourself with your  `enum Format` with /without FlagsAttribute. Is sufficient to set values to the power of 2

Comment: Yes, you can set values to the power of 2. But if you set a value to 3 without the flags attribute then that doesn't correspond to a value contained within the enum so its undefined. Whereas with the Flags attribute it should compare to two of the values combined. Check out the MSDN link, in there example where they itterate values.

Comment: in practice you need to know if your format is bold or italic, and perhaps not if your enum is "undefined". You can know it using `MyFormat myFormat = MyFormat.Bold | MyFormat.Italic; if ((myFormat & MyFormat.Bold) == MyFormat.Bold){...}` - this works with or without Flags.

Answer (score -1):

See Thomas Levesque answer. For example you then can do:

```cs
switch (test.day)
{
    case MyEnum.Monday:
    {
        //something when its monday
    }
    break;
    case MyEnum.Tuesday:
    {
        //something when its tuesday
    }
    break;
    case MyEnum.Monday | MyEnum.Tuesday:
    {
        //something when its monday and tuesday (oh the irony)
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: see my comment on the Thomas answer. Your switch will work for what case, with, or without Flags?