# Flags attribute seems to have no effect

Tags: .net, vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Public Class Form1

    <Flags> _
    Public Enum Days
        Monday = 0
        Tuesday = 1
        Wednesday = 2
    End Enum

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim s As String = (Days.Monday Or Days.Tuesday).ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The value of s becomes: Tuesday.  I would expect it to be: Monday,Tuesday as per Thomas Levesque's answer here: [FlagsAttribute what for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250648/flagsattribute-what-for).

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE After Jon Skeets answer I have tried this:

```
<Flags> _
    Public Enum Days
        None = 0
        Monday = 1
        Tuesday = 2
        Wednesday = 4
    End Enum

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim s As String = (Days.Monday And Days.Tuesday).ToString()
    End Sub
```

However, 's' now equals 'NONE'? 
Also is there any logic in the sequence of numbers i.e. 0,1,2,4,8 etc or could I use 0,1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: The OR operator compares two bits and generates a result of 1 if the bits are complementary; otherwise, it returns 0. Monday Or Tuesday means 0 or 1, it will return 1 i.e. Tuesday.

Comment: *".. I would expect it to be: Monday,Tuesday as per.."*: in that case you remove the flags attribute; which as per the thread you mentioned *"..would result in an unknown value (but it would still be valid).."*

Comment: Regrading your edit: The AND operator compares two bits and generates a result of 1 if both bits are 1; otherwise, it returns 0. Monday is 1  (i.e. 01)and Tuesday is 2 (i.e. 10) ANDing them will result in 0 which is none in your new case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're giving `Monday` a value of 0, which means it's irrelevant when you perform a bitwise-OR.

The only sensible semantic value of 0 in a `Flags`-based enum is `None`.

You should have:

```
<Flags> _
Public Enum Days
    None = 0
    Monday = 1
    Tuesday = 2
    Wednesday = 4
    Thursday = 8
    ...
End Enum
```

Note that aside from the "none" value I've included, that's the same as the values given in the post you referred to. The values are important! They're effectively what gets stored... the names are just useful for us as humans.

EDIT: Now you've updated your code, you've changed the operator from `Or` to `And`, so you're performing a bitwise AND of 1 and 2... which is 0. To be additive, you need to use `Or`.

And yes, the sequence of numbers is precisely bitwise, doubling each time: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 etc. The "none" value of 0 is just "no bits set". I suggest you read the [`FlagsAttribute` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) carefully.

Comment: Thanks +1.  I have tried this but now the value is 'NONE'.  Please see my OP for an update.

Comment: @w0051977: You're now using `And` instead of `Or`.